# RecursionError when trying to mock an iterable with an __iter__ method that returns self

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-mock

For the purpose of a unit test, I made a class whose instance is an iterable that would yield a certain sequence and then raise an exception:

```
class Iter:
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.seq = seq
        self.pos = 0

    def __next__(self):
        if self.pos == len(self.seq):
            raise Exception
        value = self.seq[self.pos]
        self.pos += 1
        return value

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

so that:

```
for value in Iter((1, 2, 3)):
    print(value)
```

would output:

```
1
2
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    for value in mocked_iterable:
  File "test.py", line 11, in __next__
    raise Exception
Exception
```

But why reinvent the wheel when `MagicMock` already has a `side_effect` attribute that should do the same? Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect), the `side_effect` attribute can be an iterable that yields either a value to be returned from the call to the mock, or an exception to raise, so it suits the purpose of mimicking the aforementioned class perfectly. I therefore created a `MagicMock` object and made its `__iter__` method return the object itself, and made its `__next__` method to have a side effect of the desired sequence and the exception:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
mocked_iterable = MagicMock()
mocked_iterable.__iter__.return_value = mocked_iterable
mocked_iterable.__next__.side_effect = [1, 2, 3, Exception]
for value in mocked_iterable:
    print(value)
```

However, this outputs:

```
...
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1005, in _mock_call
    ret_val = effect(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1793, in __iter__
    return iter(ret_val)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 939, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 944, in _mock_call
    self.called = True
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

But the question is, why is there any recursion?

I found that I can work around this "bug" by putting the self reference in `__iter__`'s `side_effect` attribute instead:

```
mocked_iterable = MagicMock()
mocked_iterable.__iter__.side_effect = [mocked_iterable]
mocked_iterable.__next__.side_effect = [1, 2, 3, Exception]
for value in mocked_iterable:
    print(value)
```

This correctly outputs:

```
1
2
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    for value in mocked_iterable:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 939, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1000, in _mock_call
    raise result
Exception
```

But is the recursion error indeed a bug, or a feature of `mock` with an unintended consequence?

Comment: You can see that mock's implementation is trying to iterate over the return value: `return iter(ret_val)` - that's why there's recursion.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's indeed a bug. It should check if `ret_val` is already an iterable (by checking if it has an `__iter__` attribute) before calling the `iter` function with it.

Comment: `__next__` should raise `StopIteration` to signal the end of the sequence. Also, `side_effect` only raises the iteration if its *value* is an exception, not just when the next value to return is an exception.

Comment: This is a *very* easy thing to spec out with a generator. A mock here is overkill unless you need some of its more specialised features.

Comment: There's a similar issue if you try modifying the `DEFAULT` `MagicMock` where it will always result in `iter([])`.  (this happens if you do `mocked_iterable.return_value.__iter__`)

Comment: Both issues can be found here:  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c6325b1c9fe60f72bb3fa4b8570a699e9e97af53/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L2034-L2042

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this is indeed a bug. Although this is an edge case.

As we can see in the source code. `mock` module expects that `iter(ret_val)` will return the unchanged iterator if `ret_val` has already been an iterator.

Well, it actually does but still needs to call `ret_val`'s `__iter__` method.